# Remove an attribute from a blob of HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a blob of HTML. How can I use jQuery to remove the `class` attribute from all anchor tags in the blob and then return the resulting HTML?

I feel like this should work, but it doesn't:

```
$(blob).filter('a').removeAttr('class').end().html()
```

(It returns the empty string)

Bonus points if you explain why my solution is wrong.

Comment: Note... as Votey worked around in his/her answer, html() returns the *inner* HTML of whatever the selector is... so if you want the html of the selected elements themselves, you need to wrap it in a div or something as Votey demonstrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
$('<div></div>').append(blob).find('a').removeAttr('class').end().html()
```

`.filter()` takes the selected elements and removes all those that aren't `<a>` tags.  `.find()` traverses into the entire tree, finding all anchor tags inside.

Comment: This doesn't work -- suppose blob is `"something <a class='test' href='#'>alkdfjs</a>"`. Your answer outputs "alkdfjs"

Comment: Ah.  I misunderstood what `blob` would be.  I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! (To be clear, given the above definition of blob, I'm looking for this output: `something <a href='#'>alkdfjs</a>`)

Comment: Nice (weird that jQuery forces you to do this kind of hack...)